# How put multiple badges inside ion-item in IONIC 2?

Tags: javascript, css, ionic2

How can I put multiple badges inside an ion-item in IONIC 2? I am doing this, but it only shows the first four badges.

```
<ion-item detail-push>            
  <ion-badge>Badge 1</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Badge 2</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Another Badge</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Another big badge</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Another very big badge</ion-badge>
</ion-item>
```

I need that ion-item grow to shows all badges. How can I do it?

The html rendered is this:

```
<ion-item class="item item-block item-md" detail-push="">
  <div class="item-inner">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
      <!--template bindings={}-->
      <ion-label class="label label-md">            
        <ion-badge class="badge badge-md">Badge 1</ion-badge>
        <ion-badge class="badge badge-md">Badge 2</ion-badge>
        <ion-badge class="badge badge-md">Another Badge</ion-badge>
        <ion-badge class="badge badge-md">Another big badge</ion-badge>
        <ion-badge class="badge badge-md">Another very big badge</ion-badge>
      </ion-label>
    </div>
    <!--template bindings={}-->
  </div>
  <div class="button-effect"></div>
</ion-item>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me:

```
<button ion-item detail-push>
    <div style="float:left; width:100%; display:block; margin-left:-10px;">
        <button ion-button style="float:left; font-size:1.2rem !important; color:#999; float:left; display:block; text-transform: capitalize;" clear>   
            Tags
        </button>
    </div>
    <ion-badge>Badge 1</ion-badge>
    <ion-badge>Badge 2</ion-badge>
    <ion-badge>Another Badge</ion-badge>
    <ion-badge>Another big badge</ion-badge>
    <ion-badge>Another very big badge</ion-badge>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting horizontal scroll for the item.

```
<ion-item detail-push>
<ion-scroll scrollX="true">            
  <ion-badge>Badge 1</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Badge 2</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Another Badge</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Another big badge</ion-badge>
  <ion-badge>Another very big badge</ion-badge>
</ion-scroll>
</ion-item>
```